# Separate original dataset into two datasets based on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a datasframe, df, where I would like to break a single dataset into 2 based on column names.

df1

**Data**

```
name    date    count   pp  ex
aa1     q122    3       30  aa7
bb1     q222    4       40  bb7
```

**Desired**

df2

```
name    date    count   pp
aa1     q122    3       30
bb1     q222    4       40
```

df3

```
ex    date    count   pp
aa7   q122    3       30
bb7   q222    4       40
```

**Doing**

```
df2 = df1.pop('ex')

df3 = df1.pop('name')
```

This does the trick of the correct column output, but the format is different. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: I'm confused. `df2 = df1.pop('ex')` would make `df2` equal the Series `ex` from `df1`, but it appears you're showing `df2` and `df3` as df1 excluding the popped column.

Comment: essentially, I am just wanting to show 2 diff dataframes: one without the ex column and one without the name column. Only difference is the format I am wanting this to arrive at (to match the desired output)

Comment: So to clarify: `df2 = df1.pop('ex')` and `df3 = df1.pop('name')` "This does the trick, but is there a more elegant way to achieve this?" is incorrect as you are not looking for the output from the provided code, but rather the shown output dataframes?

Comment: sorry I have updated that statement. 'It does the trick' in displaying the correct output columns; except the format is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there. Word of caution though..`pop` is best used when creating a dummy column. A column that will only temporarily be used and removed. May not be the optimal method for what you are doing.@slakkers answer may just be solution

```
df2=df1.copy()
df2.pop('ex')#Return item and drop from frame. Raise KeyError if not found.
df2
```

and

```
df3=df1.copy()
df3.pop('name')
df3=df3[['ex','date', 'count', 'pp']]
df3
```

Answer (score 2):

Just feed in a column list of interest.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"A":1, "B": 2, "C": 3}, {"A":11, "B": 22, "C": 23}, {"A":31, "B": 32, "C": 33}])
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1  11  22  23
2  31  32  33

df[["A", "B"]]
    A   B
0   1   2
1  11  22
2  31  32

df[["C", "A"]]
    C   A
0   3   1
1  23  11
2  33  31
```